# Web scrapping com python não traz a informação completa da pagina html

Tags: html, python, shell, beautifulsoup

Saudações pessoal, estou tentando utilizar python para poder pegar as informações da pagina http://www.nfce.se.gov.br/portal/painelMonitor.jsp , é uma pagina da sefaz onde tem o status de ping dos envios da NFC-e, porém ao usar o soup com python pra puxar as informações da pagina, ela nao me traz as informações que estão la em tempo real, ele não ta me trazendo todas as informações que eu consigo ver com o inspect F12 do browser, alguem teria alguma ideia do que pode ser ? Segue abaixo o código que estou utilizando:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


page = requests.get('http://www.nfce.se.gov.br/portal/painelMonitor.jsp')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

autorizador = soup.find(id='tabDados')

print(autorizador.prettify())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O código abaixo usa lxml para parsear a página diretamente da URL:

```
import requests, lxml.html

resp = requests.get('http://www.nfce.se.gov.br/portal/ConStatusAuto?Origem=1')
doc = lxml.html.fromstring(resp.text)
for tr in doc.xpath('//tr'):
    nome = tr[0].text_content().strip()
    print(nome.ljust(25), '|'.join('{: >7}'.format(td.text_content().strip()) 
        for td in tr.xpath('.//td')[1:]))
```

Resultado:

```
SEFAZ Amazonas                   |  783ms|  900ms|  361ms|    0ms|  900ms|  661ms|    0ms|  806ms|   50ms|  783ms|  783ms|  196ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms
SEFAZ São Paulo                  |    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms
SEFAZ Paraná                     |  429ms|1s808ms|  559ms|  433ms|1s808ms|  620ms|  429ms|  799ms|  495ms|  512ms|  521ms|  518ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms
SEFAZ Goias                      |    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms
SEFAZ Mato Grosso                |    0ms|  896ms|  310ms|  609ms|  861ms|  301ms|    0ms|  896ms|  325ms|    0ms|  476ms|  159ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms
SEFAZ Rio Grande do Sul          |  852ms|1s886ms|  974ms|  852ms|1s166ms|  964ms|  871ms|1s886ms|  986ms|  867ms|  986ms|  940ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms
SEFAZ Virtual RS                 |  761ms|5s854ms| 1s11ms|  830ms|1s245ms|  964ms|  761ms|5s854ms| 1s65ms|  899ms|  969ms|  925ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms
SEFAZ Mato Grosso do Sul         |    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms
SEFAZ Ceará                      |    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms
SEFAZ Minas Gerais               |    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms
SEFAZ Pernambuco                 |    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms
```

Comment: salvou minha vida cara, valeu, era isso mesmo que eu queria, agora vc saberia dizer como trazer somente o SEFAZ Virtual RS ?

Comment: outra coisa, como vc chegou nesse link http://www.nfce.se.gov.br/portal/ConStatusAuto?Origem=1 ?

Comment: @RafaelXavierSuarez ao solicitar a url, o servidor da SE retornará todos os dados. Cabe a você filtrar os que você quer

Comment: @RafaelXavierSuarez o link eu cheguei inspecionando a página no navegador através da aba "Network"

Answer (score 2):

As informações da página são preenchidas por código em Javascript que é executado depois que a chave é carregada. Esse codigo faz as requisições em tempo real aos vários servidores, e etc...

Com tecnologias de web-scrapping normais não é possível obter esses dados. Quando é assim, você tem duas opções: 
Tnetar olhar o código da página (como baixado pelo Python - com requests ou o framework de scrapping que estiver usando) ,  e fazer a engenharia reversa das URLs consultadas pelo Javascript e tentar fazer as mesmas consultas a partir do seu código em Python . Nesse caso, estaria até favorável fazer algo assim já que o Javascript que faz as operações não está obfuscado. Além de um pouco de código na própria página que você carrega, a maior parte do código em Javascript está na URL http://www.nfce.se.gov.br/portal/framework/js/nfce/nfc-e.js .

Essa opção, dependendo de quais dados você precisa e de quanto complexo é o código pode ser muito complicada (se for uma página com Javascript obfuscado nem tente começar por aí).

A outra opção é usar em vez do beautifulsoup, o [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) - O selenium usa um browser "real" (embora, na configuração atual, sem uma janela visível), e roda *todo* o javascript da página como numa navegação normal, inclusive efetuando outros requests de HTTP. E ele expõe uma API que permite que você veja o HTML gerado *pelo javascript executado*.

Perceba que a grande diferença é que o Selenium realmente inclui um navegador completo, com um engine javascript (por padrão ele usa o firefox, mas isso é configurável) - e permite que seu programa em Python veja a página como ela ficou *enquanto* o Javascript está em execução.

Esta segunda opção definitivamente é mais apropriada para você seguir, uma vez que não vai estar sujeito a ficar horas analizando o código Javascript da página e tentando replicar o seu comportamento, apenas para em algumas semanas ou meses, os autores mudarem o código e você ter que refazer todo o trabalho. Com Selenium você pega o HTML já renderizado da página e pode proceder a isolar os dados que precisa com o Beautfulsoup normalmente.